# Event.h library using event_new() function in C

Tags: c, pointers, events

First off, I am not a programmer, I do electrical engineering.  I have done some programming, but would never say that I am a good programmer.  This question will probably be downvoted, but that is ok because I have been trying to do this for two months now.

I no nothing about event.h, but I have an existing code that works and uses this. It goes like this (I changed some things to hide information, but the code works):

```
struct event_base   *base;
struct event        *read_event;
struct event        *signal_event;

typedef struct sample_ctx {
    sens_handle_t   *sens_handler;
    sens_data_t     data;
} sample_ctx_t;

// signal handler to break the event loop
void
signal_handler(evutil_socket_t sock, short event, void *user_data)
{
    event_base_loopbreak(base);
}

// receive callback
void
sens_recv_cb(evutil_socket_t sock, short event, void *user_data)
{
    static int i = 0;
    int        timeout = 0;

    static struct timeval   timestamp;
    struct timeval          timestamp2;
    struct timeval          diff;
    sens_status_t           status;
    sample_ctx_t            *ctx;

    ctx = (sample_ctx_t *)user_data;

    if (i == 0) {
        gettimeofday(&timestamp, NULL);
        i = 1;
    }
    status = sens_read(&ctx->data, ctx->sens_handler);


    if ((status == SENS_SUCCESS)     &&
       !isnan(ctx->data.info1)  &&
       !isnan(ctx->data.info2)   &&
       !isnan(ctx->data.info3)      &&
       !isnan(ctx->data.info4)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%lf %lf %lf %lf\n",
                               ctx->data.info1,
                               ctx->data.info2,
                               ctx->data.info3,
                               ctx->data.info4);
        gettimeofday(&timestamp, NULL);
    } else {
        gettimeofday(&timestamp2, NULL);

        timersub(&timestamp2, &timestamp, &diff);

        timeout = diff.tv_sec + (diff.tv_usec / 1000000);

    }
}


int main()
{
int fd;

status_t status;


sample_ctx_t ctx;

memset(&ctx, 0, sizeof(ctx));


status = sensor_open(&fd, &ctx.gps_handler);
if (status != V2X_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Open failed ... sensor might not be running\n");
    goto deinit_4;
}

base = event_base_new();
if (!base) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create event base\n");
    goto deinit_3;
}

// register for the read events
read_event = event_new(base, fd, EV_PERSIST|EV_READ, sens_recv_cb, &ctx);
if (!read_event) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create read event\n");
    goto deinit_2;
}

// register for the SIGINT signal on ctrl + c key combo
signal_event = evsignal_new(base, SIGINT, signal_handler, NULL);
if (!signal_event) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create signal event\n");
    goto deinit_1;
}

event_add(read_event, NULL);

evsignal_add(signal_event, NULL);

event_base_dispatch(base);

evsignal_del(signal_event);
deinit_1:
    event_free(read_event);
deinit_2:
    event_base_free(base);
deinit_3:
    sensor_close(ctx.sens_handler);
deinit_4:
    return 0;
}
```

This code retrieves data from a sensor and prints it to the screen.  It's purpose is pretty simple, but the way it has to be done is what is complicated; for me at least.

Ok, so in the sens_recv_cb function, the ctx->data is printed to the screen, but I need to access that in the main function.  The only time this function is called is in the event_new function in main.  Is there a way get that data in main?  Like lets say I just want to print ctx->data.info1 in main while still printing out everything from before in the sens_recv_cb function.

Is what I want to do possible without changing the entire code?

Comment: You just need to save the data at file scope, where it's accessible from `main`. Take a look at the docs on `memcpy`.

Comment: @jwdonahue When I put memcpy in the sens_recv_cb function and print out in Main, if I put the printf before event_base_dispatch() it puts 0.0000 and then prints out info1, info2, info3, info4 repeatedly.  If I put printf after the event_base_dispatch() it prints out info1, info2, ... repeatedly, then when I stop it, it prints out the last value of info1.  Is there a way to print out from memcpy, then info1, info2, info3, info4, then from mempcy, then info1, info2, ...? or once it enters the event_base_dispatch() it doesn't leave until you stop the code?

Comment: @jwdonahue sorry, I didn't see that below was also your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `main` and `sens_recv_cb` are asynchronous, you'll need a way to signal between them and a way for the call-back to store the data. You can combine both with a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list):

```
struct node {
    sample_ctx_t data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
}
struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *tail = NULL;
```

The event handler adds to the head of the list and the main function removes them from the tail. It's a FIFO. You'll need to use [atomic operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic) when reading/writing data to the list. The links provide what you need to know, and if you search, you'll find lots of example code around here and at other sites. You can probably find an open source, thread-safe linked list implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=linked+list).

Basically, when the list is empty, there's nothing for main to consume.